# WARNING: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc undefined" when compiling a kernel module in RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, kernel, modules

I recently bought a new RPi 4 and tried to install the module I ran on the old RPi 3B (which ran successfully).
Now, when trying to install the same module on the RPi 4 I get 2 warnings when compiling the kernel module -
**WARNING: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_const_cmp4" [/home/pi/AMAT/ens_adc_3/ens_adc_3.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc" [/home/pi/AMAT/ens_adc_3/ens_adc_3.ko] undefined!**

When trying to install the module, I get -
**insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ens_adc_3.ko: Unknown symbol in module**

I installed the most updated kernel headers and I couldn't find any solutions when I Googled.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I formatted the SD card, installed Rasbpian, and all the relevant packages again. in one of the packages I was asked if I want code coverage for fuzzing installed (KCOV), and this time I replied no.
The problem no longer occurred when compiling the kernel module.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.